# PayPal Sandbox Negative Testing of PartialSuccess

Tags: paypal

Does the PayPal Sandbox API Negative Testing allow you to produce a "PartialSuccess" result?

I am attempting to reproduce in the PayPal Sandbox a situation in production that is causing problems. The situation is that we have orders with items from multiple sellers, which results in multiple payments. Sometimes when we call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` some of those payments fail (generally with error code 13113), while others succeed. The Ack from DoExpressCheckoutPayment == "PartialSuccess" in this case.

It appears there are problems in our logic to deal with this situation. Therefore, I want to troubleshoot this in the sandbox, and I have turned on Negative Testing.

However, the Sandbox is not behaving as expected. If I create an order with two items from different sellers, the first item seems to control the whole transaction.

- If item #1 has a price which corresponds to an error code (e.g. $131.13), then the transaction comes back as Ack == "Failure" even if item #2 does not cause any error.
- If I switch the order of the items, so the non-error item is #1 and the error item is #2, the whole transaction goes through with Ack == "Success" with no error triggered at all.

I can't find any documentation about the combination of Negative Testing and PartialSuccess. Am I doing something wrong, or does PayPal Sandbox just not support testing this situation?

Comment: Question is confusing. Please spend more time isolating the important details.

Comment: Edited. Is that any less confusing?